# Running junit testcases in parallel using maven

Tags: java, maven, junit

I added in my pom.xml the following plugin to run test classes in parallel

> ```
> <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>     <configuration>
>       <parallel>classes</parallel>
>       <threadCount>10</threadCount>
>       <systemPropertyVariables>
>         <profile.name>${profile.name}</profile.name>
>       </systemPropertyVariables>
>       <forkCount>1</forkCount>
>       <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
>     </configuration>
>   </plugin>
> ```

And i have

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
   test_1.class,
   test_2.class
})
```

when i run it as  a junit test it runs sequential not parallel... any help ??

Answer (score 1):

`<forkCount>1</forkcount>` means 1 thread!

> The default setting is **forkCount=1/reuseForks=true**, which means that maven-surefire-plugin creates **one new JVM process** to execute all tests in **one Maven module**.

from: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html#Forked_Test_Execution

To run them in parallel, you should choose a `forkCount > 1`, and (to be safe) also `<reuseForks>false</reuseForks>`.

Comment: i amde what you told me and removed the parallel & thread count tag and still runs in sequential .. any help ?

Answer (score 1):

I think `<parallel>classes</parallel>` means tests belonging to two different classes will be run in parallel.

`<parallel>methods</parallel>` means tests belonging to same class will also be run in parallel. You can also use `classesAndMethods`.

- `methods`: This instructs Maven to run individual test methods within a single test class concurrently. Parallelism happens at the level of individual test methods.
- `classesAndMethods`: This tells Maven to execute entire test classes in parallel across multiple forked JVMs. Additionally, within each forked JVM, individual test methods can also be run concurrently using threads. Parallelism happens at the level of entire test classes and then methods within each class.

Note: Both `methods` and `classesAndMethods` can be combined with the `forkCount` parameter to control the number of forked JVMs used.